# Using React Three Fiber, I want to recreate this method from Java WorldWide

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

Trying to access the dynamic latitude and longitude of a globe when moussing over a position on it. Java World Wide has a method to do that, but I'm having a hell of a time trying to recreate it using React Three Fiber. This is also my first time working with React or Three in general, so any advice is greatly appreciated. Here's the Java World Wide Method:

```
private void handleCursorPositionChange(PositionEvent event)
{
    Position newPos = event.getPosition();
    if (newPos != null)
    {
        latDisplay = makeAngleDescription("Lat", newPos.getLatitude(), coordDecimalPlaces);
        lonDisplay = makeAngleDescription("Lon", newPos.getLongitude(), coordDecimalPlaces);
        elevDisplay = makeCursorElevationDescription(
            eventSource.getModel().getGlobe().getElevation(newPos.getLatitude(), newPos.getLongitude()));

        //Need to force an extra draw.  without this the displayed value lags the actual when just moving cursor
        if ((previousPos != null) && (previousPos.getLatitude().compareTo(newPos.getLatitude()) != 0)
            && (previousPos.getLongitude().compareTo(newPos.getLongitude()) != 0))
            this.eventSource.redraw();
    }
    else
    {
        latDisplay = "";
        lonDisplay = Logging.getMessage("term.OffGlobe");
        elevDisplay = "";
    }

    previousPos = newPos;
}
```

I feel like this shouldn't be too hard, but I have no idea how to find the live lat lon information from the globe.

Edit: I found this method in the lib.dom.d.ts file in the node_modules library root. would i be able to use it to do what I've been trying to do?

```
interface GeolocationCoordinates {
readonly accuracy: number;
readonly altitude: number | null;
readonly altitudeAccuracy: number | null;
readonly heading: number | null;
readonly latitude: number;
readonly longitude: number;
readonly speed: number | null;    }
```

Comment: lol it was hard, but I can kind of explain how I did it if anyone wants to know